# Usage of the word »schlimm«

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My friends from Bavaria wrote to me:

> Du hast unser Mitgefühl. Schlimm.

If I understand correctly, they expressed their sympathy, but why »schlimm«? I was embarrassed to ask them about it.

Answer (score 9):

> "Schlimm."

is just short for

> "Es ist wirklich schlimm, was passiert ist"
>
> ("It's really bad/sad what happened")

In this context, the difference between "schlimm" and "schlecht" (["Schlimm" vs. "Schlecht"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/schlimm-vs-schlecht) - esp. Hauser's answer herein) might also be interesting. "Schlimm" is the correct one to use here.