# Schlechter hören vs. schlimmer hören

Tags: word-choice

Heute bei Artzbesuch habe ich gesagt:

> Ich höre seit 2 Wochen schlimmer mit dem rechten Ohr.

Worauf hat mich mein muttersprachlicher Gegenüber gefragt:

> Sie meinen "schlimmer" im Sinne "schlechter"?

Gibt es Unterschied bei der Verwendung der Worte je nach Kontext?

Comment: **Schlimm** bedeutet **sehr sehr schlecht**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schlecht bezieht sich auf den direkten Vergleich in diesem Fall wie gut das Ohr hört.
Der Maßstab ist in dem Sinn neutral.

Schlimm sagt auch aus, dass die Situation emotional negativ bewertet wird, und die Erwartung ist dass weitere Verschlechterung daraus kommt.

Zum Beispiel: Es ist schlimm, dass ich auf dem rechten Ohr schlecht höre.

Gute Diskussion (auf Englisch) bei ["Schlimm" vs. "Schlecht"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2457/297)

Comment: In der Tat ist *schlimm* nicht synonym zu *schlecht*, sondern der Bereich der Verwendung ist eingeschränkter. Es kann auch je nach Kontext im Sinne von "schwer(wiegend)" verwendet werden, etwa in "Ich habe eine schlimme Entzündung am Ohr".